# Irregular output while using Priority Heap/Comparator

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I am trying to use a priority Queue and was trying to get the numbers arranged in the reverse order [descending orders].

I implemented a comparator, and used the reverse convention as compared to natural order hoping that I would get numbers in reverse order.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        PriorityQueue<Integer> Descending = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(10,stats.new    
        minComparator());

        Descending.add(5);
        Descending.add(2);
        Descending.add(7);

        while(Descending.size() > 0)
        {
               System.out.print(Descending.remove());

        }    

    }

class minComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer int1, Integer int2)
    {
        if(int1.intValue() < int1.intValue())
            return 1;
        else if(int1.intValue() > int1.intValue())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

```
5 7 2
```

This is neither ascending nor descending !. Can someone please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: what you need is:  `java.util.Collections.reverseOrder()` as comparator AND to learn and use debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare the same number `int1` to itself instead of `int1` and `int2`

```
int1.intValue() < int1.intValue()
```

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest a simplification?

```
@Override
public int compare(Integer int1, Integer int2)
{
    return int2.compareTo( int1 );
}
```

Comment: Thnx, thats much more cleaner. The correct syntax:  return new Integer(int2).compareTo(  int1 );

Comment: Right. Thanks. but you don't need `new`.